# Translating an integer into two-byte hexadecimal with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, raspberry-pi

I need to take an integer (for example, -200) and change it into a hexadecimal (FF 38), then into an integer 0-255 to send via serial. The example I was given was:

```
-200 = hex FF38 = [hex FF] [hex 38] = [255] [56]
```

I've tried using `struct.pack('>h', -200)` but that returned the incorrect value. I also tried `hex()` but that returned a negative hex value that was incorrect as well.

I don't know what else I should be trying.

Comment: Do you need to send a decimal integer `b'255'` (three bytes) or just a  as a byte: `b'\xff'` (single byte)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> hex(struct.unpack('>H', struct.pack('>h', -200))[0])
'0xff38'
```

First, you pack the -200 as a **signed 2-byte short int**. Then you unpack that data as an **unsigned 2-byte short int**. This gives you 65336, of which `hex` is `ff38`

---

If you need to send `0-255` integers, this might work better:

```
>>> struct.unpack('>BB', struct.pack('>h', -200))
(255, 56)
>>> struct.unpack('>BB', struct.pack('>h', 200))
(0, 200)
```

Where you're unpacking into two **unsigned chars**

---

Requisite [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html#format-characters) on `struct`

Comment: This works great for positive numbers, but what about negative numbers? I tried 200 and -200 and got the same thing.

Comment: You shouldn't have... I've edited my answer with an example of each

Comment: Had the packing been unsigned, it would have raised an exception: `struct.error: integer out of range for 'H' format code`

Comment: +1. To be clear: `struct.pack('>h', n)` converts an integer `assert n.bit_length() <= 16` into two-byte sequence: `'\xff\x38'`. No other calls are necessary unless OP wants a decimal representation for some reason then `map(str, bytearray(b'\xff\x38')) == ['255', '56']`

Comment: Yes, I used the below method and it worked perfectly, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two's complement arithmetic and some string slicing:

```
hex(200 - (1 << 16)) #2 bytes -> 16 bits
Out[26]: '-0xff38'

int(hex(200 - (1 << 16))[-4:-2], 16)
Out[28]: 255

int(hex(200 - (1 << 16))[-2:], 16)
Out[29]: 56
```

Note that you'll have to take care to correctly handle non-negative numbers (i.e. don't take the two's complement) and when the length of the string returned by `hex` is of varying length.